# FormsAuthentication redirecting to login page when visiting root of website

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication

I wanted to use FormsAuthentication to secure my static files as well on my site, so I followed the instructions located here http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/244/how-to-take-advantage-of-the-iis7-integrated-pipeline/ under title "Enabling Forms Authentication for the Entire Application".

Now though, when I try to visit the site by going directly to http://www.mysite.com I get redirected to http://www.mysite.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f instead of it using my DefaultDocument I have set. I can go to my default document by just visiting http://www.mysite.com/Home.aspx without any issues because it is set to allow anonymous access.

Is there something I need to add into my web.config file to make iis7 allow anonymous access to the root? I tried adding  with anonymous access but no such luck.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Both Home and the Login form allow anonymous.

```
<location path="Home.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Login.aspx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Login form is set as the loginUrl

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms protection="All" loginUrl="Login.aspx">
  </forms>
</authentication>
```

Default document is set as Home.aspx

```
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="Home.aspx" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

I have not removed any of the iis7 default documents. However, Home.aspx is first in the priority.

Comment: Post your web.config settings.

Comment: Also... is Home.aspx the *only* document listed in the default documents in IIS?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824951/forms-authentication-ignoring-default-document

Comment: Please see my answer regarding removing the ExtensionlessUrl modules [Forms Authentication Ignoring Default Document:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824951/forms-authentication-ignoring-default-document)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look: [Allowing anonymous access to default page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916723/allowing-anonymous-access-to-default-page)

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this:

```
<authorization>    
  <allow users="?" />  
</authorization>
```

I think that will fix it.

Comment: It doesn't fix anything - it just disables authorization altogether defeating the purpose of having it