# How can I set Microsoft Identity to respect default file names

Tags: c#, webforms, asp.net-identity

I am attempting to migrate from Forms Authentication / Membership to asp.net identity.

One issue I have encountered: If I set the LoginPath to "/account/", logged out users end up with an infinite redirect loop (not really; it keeps extending the returnURL until the server blocks the request for having an overly long query string).  This occurs on `/account/`, but `/account/default.aspx` is accessible to logged out users.  I believe that the issue is that somehow default documents are treated differently by the OWIN middleware than they are by forms authentication/IIS.  Currently, "default.aspx" is configured as a Default Document.

I tried setting using `UseFileServer` to set `DefaultFileNames` to include "default.aspx", but this did not seem to help.  I also tried using `path="." inheritInChildApplications=false"` instead of `path="default.aspx"`, but this caused a, "Config section 'system.web/authorization' already defined" exception, presumably because it overlapped with the previous system.web declaration.

I realize that there are several possible work-arounds:

- tolerate `default.aspx` in the path:
- use `MapPageRoutes` instead of relying on default pages
- set the web.config to allow /account and then use location path to manually disable every subdirectory

Is there a way to convince Microsoft Identity that loading `/account/` does not require authentication without using the workarounds in the bullet points above?

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions() {
                DefaultFilesOptions = {DefaultFileNames = {"default.aspx"}}});
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/account/")
    });
}

<!--/account/web.config-->
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="activeuser" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>   
    <location path="Default.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voting to close my own question as a duplicate.  For reference, this can be resolved by modifying the root web.config as follows:

```
<urlMappings>
  <add url="~/account/" mappedUrl="~/account/default.aspx"/>
</urlMappings>
```

Somehow I completely failed to find https://stackoverflow.com/a/19154854/18192 while investigating this problem.