# IIS Keeps Redirecting to Login.aspx when I set Default.aspx as default page

Tags: asp.net, iis

IIS Keeps Redirecting me to `Login.aspx` when I set `Default.aspx` as default page. In my dev environment its working fine, I get to the right page, but as soon as I publish and try from the IIS server login.aspx always comes first.

I have made sure anon users are allowed :

```
  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And its set as default url (further down the config) :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

I even set the default page in IIS, but it resets it every time on publish.

Comment: Are you using IIS7? `but it resets it every time on publish.` that's because the default page is stored in the web.config in IIS 7 under `system.WebServer` - so you are overwriting it and removing the setting when you publish.

Comment: @vcsjones sorry I dont understand, I dont know how I am overwriting it, and with what. My code above is all thats in my config related to Default.aspx, so if I did overwrite it should it not still make the default.aspx the default page?

Comment: Found an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824951/forms-authentication-ignoring-default-document

Answer (score 5):

Try adding the Authenticated User to the security property of the web folder in IIS. Give the modify privilege (Read, Write, Modify, List Folder Content, Read & execute) to this user.

This of course should only be a temporary situation to verify that you have a permission issue. You should consider setting proper permissions for site users.

//Peace

Answer (score 0):

I spent about 6 hours debugging the issue. Our website was working fine, and suddenly it started redirecting to login page instead of default page (unauthenticated). Our web.config included all authentication/authorization settings correctly.

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="MyAuth" path="/" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>

  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="default.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
...
  </system.webServer>

  <location path="default.htm">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

...

SOLUTION: You need to remove Extensionless URL feature from your website.
Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2526854/users-may-be-redirected-to-the-login-page-of-an-asp-net-4-application

```
<system.webServer>

     <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
     </handlers>

     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

</system.webServer>
```

After the fix, the website was back to normal.