# how to use sso just for some pages (continued)

Tags: c#, asp.net, single-sign-on

I have a web application. I use sso for authentication. I put the code showed below in web.config page.

```
<authorization>
   <deny users="?">
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="https://sso.***.***.***/login" timeout="30" defaultUrl="~/Index.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" 
    slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
</authentication>
<location path="index.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

If users click http://website.com/index.aspx , no login needed. but other pages, they need login first(go to sso page). This works well. My problem is if user click http://website.com/ ,they still need go to login first. That's not what I want. I need it will go to index page directly.

Please help

Comment: See here for possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824951/forms-authentication-ignoring-default-document

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks Jason, last time you helped me on this issue. I appreciate it!

Comment: I didn't realize that, that's funny!

Comment: You save my day again!