# Need guidance in debugging this DNN issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-settings

I'm a beginner with DotNetNuke and am having trouble debugging this problem.  We are using DNN version 5.

On our local development machines our DNN site renders just fine.  But we recently deployed to our test server and on there the site only renders fine when logged in as the Host.  When viewing the site as just a normal visitor, all the styles are messed up -- it is just a white page with images gone and menus stacked vertically.

### Clues / Notes:

1. We recently added a new .ascx and module
2. There are javascript errors, but it hard to tell what is causing them
3. You may ask about the Log Viewer screen.  I looked there and I see exceptions, but I think the exceptions there are unrelated ( will look into this)
4. Works fine in our local dev environment
5. In server, only renders fine when logged on as Host

What are some steps I can take to try to debug this?  Where else can I look besides the Event Viewer to see what is going on here?

Thanks!

Comment: Did the test server's site work prior to your latest code deployment, or was this a totally new setup on the test server?

Comment: @ChrisHammond It was working before.  Not a new setup.  Thanks

Comment: I would start by comparing the HTML source of the page generated when you are logged in as HOST to when you are not, and see if you can track down if something isn't being loaded on the page (likely jquery)

Comment: @ChrisHammond Thanks.  That sounds like a good thing to try

Comment: Does this new control need some js components like jquery ui for example? If so, assure you're explicitly registering needed scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3831419/614263

Due to permission settings it looks like IIS was blocking requests from the root to javascripts and css files.  When looking at the Network traffic in FireFox  I noticed that 404 errors were coming from "login.aspx?ReturnURL=../../blahblah.css"

Thanks for all your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What is the "new .ascx" that you deployed?  Is that a skin page?

If something is wrong in the skin page and it is the default site page (under Admin > Site Settings), that would explain why non-admin users have issues, but Admin/Host users (where the site's Edit skin is working) don't have issues.