# How to pass an authenticated user to a nested HttpContext in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, httpmodule, digest-authentication

I authenticate a user in my HttpModule (in `AuthenticateRequest` event handler). I set the authenticated user to `((HttpApplication)sender).Context.User`. However the user is lost, because the `DefaultDocumentModule` creates another `HttpContext` which no longer contains the authenticated user.

Any solution for this?

(I was trying to save the authenticated user to a `ThreadStatic` field, but this is not safe. Then, I was trying to save the user to `HttpRequest.Items`, but this is also lost.)

**Update - Detailed information:**

I am using a digest authentication (not the build-in IIS based, which works with AD only). The authentication is performed in `AuthenticateRequest` event handler of a `HttpModule`. The problem is that the `AuthenticateRequest` is being invoked twice. Because `DefaultDocumentModule` (which transfers the request from '/' to e.g. '/Default.aspx') creates another `HttpContext` for '/Default.aspx'.

I do not know how to pass the information from the first `HttpContext` (for '/') to the second `HttpContext` (for '/Default.aspx') that the request is already authenticated.

Comment: Possible solution - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824951/forms-authentication-ignoring-default-document/5549254#5549254

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin How this helps me?

Comment: Well, I was trying to guess what problem do you actually have. Could you post some more information on what you're trying to achieve? Maybe there is another approach for your problem instead of saving HttpContext in different places?